# Creating a ListPlot From Imported Excel file with errors

Tags: plotting, import, warning-messages, excel

I'm learning mathematica, and right now trying to plot a graph with error bars. What I would like to do is to import 3 lists with x values(1/viscosity), y values(permeance), and error values, and plot this using listplot. I can plot the x vs y values using "Thread" function, however when I try to use "Around" to include errors, I either get problems or no graphs at all. Is it possible to plot the graph in this fashion (I don't want to add error values one by one since I will be having a large number of data points produced, and I would like to keep importing my data from a previously produced excel files).

Example:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sR0U.png

Code:

```
viscosityinverse = 
Import["C:\\Users\\ilkvi\\Desktop\\Professional\\0-METU CHE \
PhD\\2-Research\\0-Experimental\\Flux Experiments\\Viscosity vs \
Permeance\\Hagen Poiseuille Equations.xlsx", {"Data", 1, All, 2}]

viscosityinverse = Drop[viscosityinverse, 1]

permeance = 
Import["C:\\Users\\ilkvi\\Desktop\\Professional\\0-METU CHE \
PhD\\2-Research\\0-Experimental\\Flux Experiments\\Viscosity vs \
Permeance\\Hagen Poiseuille Equations.xlsx", {"Data", 1, All, 3}]

permeance = Drop[permeance, 1]

error = Import[
"C:\\Users\\ilkvi\\Desktop\\Professional\\0-METU CHE \
PhD\\2-Research\\0-Experimental\\Flux Experiments\\Viscosity vs \
Permeance\\Hagen Poiseuille Equations.xlsx", {"Data", 1, All, 4}]

error = error[error, 1]

ListPlot[Thread[{viscosityinverse, About[Thread[permeance,error]]}]]
```

Comment: Please, provide the code you have used so far to import and plot your data.

Comment: Uploaded the code.

Comment: 1. Import your data only once with ``data = Import["..." , {"Data", 1, 2 ;; All}];``. 2. Use ``ListPlot[MapThread[Around, {data[[All, 2]], data[[All, 3]]}]]``.

Answer (score 1):

```
 table = {{"", "1/Viscosity", "Permeance", "Error"}, 
      {"EG", 2.22`*^10, 2.57`, 0}, 
      {"DMSO", 8.7`*^10, 14.09`, 1}, 
      {"Ethanol", 3.03`*^11, 53.67`, 2}, 
      {"UP", 3.6`*^11, 67.5`, 5}, 
      {"Methanol",  6.12`*^11, 110.33`, 16},
      {"Toluene", 6.55`*^11, 101.5`, 0},
      {"EthylAcetate", 8.45`*^11, 112, 0}};

{viscosityinverse, permeance, error} = Transpose @ table[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]];


ListPlot[Thread[{viscosityinverse,  Around @@@ Thread[{permeance, error}]}]]
```

[image]

***Variations:***

Add labels:

```
ListPlot[AssociationThread[table[[2 ;;, 1]], 
  Thread[{viscosityinverse,  Around @@@ Thread[{permeance, error}]}]], 
ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Add the option `LabelingFunction -> Tooltip` to show labels in tooltips:

[image]

Alternatively, as suggested by Bob Hanlon in comments, use

```
ListPlot[Tooltip[{#, #2}, #3]& @@@
  Thread[{viscosityinverse,  Around @@@ Thread[{permeance,error}], table[[2;;, 1]]}]]
```

to get the same result.

Comment: The OP could also add tooltips with `ListPlot[Tooltip @@@Transpose[{Thread[{viscosityinverse, Around @@@ Thread[{permeance, error}]}], table[[2 ;;, 1]]}]]` For this data `Callout` could be used, but the OP refers to a large amount of data which would make `Callout` too cluttered.